# How to get value of tinymce in ng-model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, tinymce-4

Scenario:
 I am using **tinymce** WYSWYG control in a ng-view.Now on ng-click of button, I need to collect the value of the control & pass to my controller.

```
<textarea id="mytextarea"  ui-tinymce ng-model="msg"></textarea>
 //js
 app.module('myApp',['ui-tinymce'])
```

But when I am inspecting the value in console, I am getting

```html
<p> <br data-mce-bogus='1'> </p>
```

If I exclude  ui-tinymce from the control, I get msg=undefined.

Plus,
In this control, I see insert image, insert video option, but I don't see option to insert/attach file(like pdf/word/etc)

Comment: WHere's the code you are using to get values? Should always have a dot in `ng-model`. What does `attach file` mean? You can't attach a file to wysiwyg html but you can link to a file

Answer (score 0):

see link below:

[ui-tinymce](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce)

in tinymce you can only insert image,video,.. because those are html media